# mplab-ide on debian can't program device (nothing happens)

Tags: debian, mplab

i'm quite new in Debian, and i'm totally confused with my problem.

Im using MPLAB X IDE to program my processor using pickit3. I can check the connection, the device is recognised, i can read from the device, but when i try to write my program, nothing happens. The button goes grey, output is empty, and that's it.

please tell me at least where to look because without any errors or warnings i'm lost.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i managed to deal with compiling problem.

I had to install build-essential.

Problem Solved